# How to loop an array that has an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

could you please help me to solve this code? I need to sum the numbers. With this code I get only "017, 1, 1311 etc"

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, numbers: [1,] },
    { id: 2, numbers: [7, 1, 13] },
    { id: 3, numbers: [11, 11, 3, 3] },
    { id: 4, numbers: [4, 22, 8, 4, 6, 2] },
  ];

let totalResult = 0;

array.forEach(item => { 
  totalResult += item.numbers;
}); 

console.log(totalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.numbers` is an Array i.e: `numbers: [7, 1, 13]`.
By doing i.e: `totalResult += item.numbers` you're basically concatenating an Array.toString() to a Number.
`[1, 2, 3].toString()` will equal `"1,2,3"` - then `0 += "1,2,3"` results in `"01,2,3"`.

Instead, [***reduce*** your array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to Number:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 1, numbers: [1]},
  {id: 2, numbers: [7, 1, 13]},
  {id: 3, numbers: [11, 11, 3, 3]},
  {id: 4, numbers: [4, 22, 8, 4, 6, 2]},
];

const tot = array.reduce((n, item) => n + item.numbers.reduce((n, i) => n + i), 0);

console.log(tot); // 96
```

Comment: Roko C.Buljan - how to use it with a function like this? Its not working. function sum4() {
  let totalRes = 0;
   const array = [
  {id: 1, numbers: [1]},
  {id: 2, numbers: [7, 1, 13]},
  {id: 3, numbers: [11, 11, 3, 3]},
  {id: 4, numbers: [4, 22, 8, 4, 6, 2]},
];

  const tot = array.reduce((n, item) => n + item.numbers.reduce((n, i) => n + i), 0);
  }

  if (totalRes === 105) {
    return "yes!";
  }
}

console.log(sum4());

Comment: @Node.jsMaster why do you have `let totalRes = 0;` in that function? You cannot use a variable outside of a function `totalRes` - Also notice that the variable is now called `tot`.

Comment: What you might want is: https://jsfiddle.net/7fajgLzb/

Answer (score -1):

`item` is an object in your forEach loop, so you have to loop through `item.numbers` to get the actual number and then add with `totalResult`.

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, numbers: [1] },
    { id: 2, numbers: [7, 1, 13] },
    { id: 3, numbers: [11, 11, 3, 3] },
    { id: 4, numbers: [4, 22, 8, 4, 6, 2] },
  ];

let totalResult = 0;

array.forEach(item => { 
  item?.numbers.forEach(num => {
    totalResult += num;
  })
}); 

console.log(totalResult);
```

If you wanna a function that returns something conditionally, here it is -

```
function sumOfArray(arr, lookingFor) {
  let totalResult = 0;
  
  arr.forEach(item => {
    item?.numbers.forEach(num => {
      totalResult += num;
    })
  });

  return totalResult === lookingFor ? 'yes' : 'no';
}

const array = [
  { id: 1, numbers: [1] },
  { id: 2, numbers: [7, 1, 13] },
  { id: 3, numbers: [11, 11, 3, 3] },
  { id: 4, numbers: [4, 22, 8, 4, 6, 2] },
];

console.log(sumOfArray(array, 96));
```

Comment: Robin, how to use your code with a function that returns? like if (totalResult === 105) {
    return "yes";

Comment: @Node.jsMaster update answer